# i can't add an id to the object in a foreach

Tags: javascript, dojo

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object HTMLDivElement] has no method 'setAttribute'
I keep getting this error when I try to add an id an element in the object.

this is the line that is crapping out on me

dojo.attr(query(".toggle_section", object),"id",i);

```
function toggleClass(){
require(["dojo/on",
         "dojo/query",
         "dojo/dom-class"
], 
function(on, query, domClass) {
    query(".toggle-container").forEach(function(object, i){
        var btn_toggle = query(".toggle", object);
        dojo.attr(query(".toggle_section", object),"id",i);
        on(btn_toggle, "click", function(evt){

            domClass.toggle(object, "closed");
            evt.preventDefault();
        });
    });
});
}

<div class="toggle-container">
            <a class="toggle" href="#" title="toggle profile">PROFILE</a>
            <div class="toggle_section">
                <p>hidden content</p>
            </div>              
        </div>
```

Comment: I am not using dojo, just a guess: does query(".toggle_section", object) return an array of divs or one div? Seems you are calling getAttribute on an array object.

Comment: Thank you dragon66 is was an array of objects i needed to add [0] to the end of the query
 dojo.attr(query(".toggle_section", object)[0],"id",i);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add [0] to the end of my query so that it would select the first and in this case only instance of the .toggle_section element.

```
dojo.attr(query(".toggle_section", object)[0],"id",i);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between `dojo/dom-*` modules like `dojo/dom`, `dojo/dom-style`, `dojo/dom-attr`, ... and `dojo/query`. The first serie of modules allow you to change **one DOM node** at a time (either by referencing a DOM node or an ID).

However, the `dojo/query` module returns a `NodeList` which is actually an array of DOM nodes with some extra functions.

To change an attribute, you can either choose to use `dojo/dom-attr` (that's the AMD version of `dojo.attr()`), but this means you can't work with a `NodeList` so you will actually have to get the Nth value of your list, like you did in your answer (`query("...")[0]`).

A better solution would be to use the [`dojo/NodeList-dom`](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/NodeList-dom.html) module, this module allows you do use the DOM functions I described earlier (`dojo/dom-style`, `dojo/dom-attr`, ...) but on a `NodeList` itself. To use it, you do the following:

```js
query(".toggle_section", object).attr("id", 1);
```

But you have to load the `dojo/NodeList-dom` module. You might ask what the difference is, well, in the code above you can still work with your `NodeList` and use all of its benefits.

A complete example can be found on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a6Q3z/).

---

***Note***: *I know you already have your answer, but this answer might be useful for future references.*

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to either:

- require in "`dojo/dom-attr`" and use `domAttr.set(node, attribute, value)`

or

- require in "`dojo`" base and use `dojo.attr(node, attribute, value)` as you already are

Comment: Thank you for the help but is was as simple as added [0] to the query.
dojo.attr(query(".toggle_section", object)[0],"id",i);